# VB.Net ByteArray Memory Leak

Tags: vb.net, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have read pretty much every post on here regarding byte arrays in the .net framework and how the GC works, but I am still at a loss. First off, the code I am working with:

```
    Public Sub SomeFunction(ByVal page As Integer, ByVal xml As String)

        Dim fileBytes As Byte()

        Using imageStream As New IO.FileStream(_imageFile, IO.FileMode.Open)

            fileBytes = Array.CreateInstance(GetType(Byte), imageStream.Length)

            imageStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, imageStream.Length)
            imageStream.Close()

        End Using

        Using ms As New IO.MemoryStream(fileBytes)

            Dim tiff As New Atalasoft.Imaging.Codec.Tiff.TiffFile

            tiff.Read(ms)

            Dim tag = tiff.Images(page - 1).Tags.LookupTag(58000)

            If tag IsNot Nothing Then
                tiff.Images(page - 1).Tags.Remove(tag)
            End If

            tag = New Atalasoft.Imaging.Metadata.TiffTag(58000, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml))
            tiff.Images(page - 1).Tags.Add(tag)

            tiff.Save(_imageFile)

        End Using

    End Sub
```

At the start of the method, I am setting fileBytes to Array.CreateInstance... and then towards the bottom I am saving the image file. This means that I HAVE to reload the ByteArray every time because the file is changing that I am looking at, so I can't just re-use. Everything is inside using statements and fileBytes SHOULD be destroyed when execution leaves the method but it is NEVER cleared and memory keeps incrementing until a SystemOutOfMemoryException occurs. If the GC doesn't release memory until it is needed supposedly, it is def not releasing it here even though it IS needed. How can I get fileBytes to release its memory in between calls to SomeFunction()?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried defining `fileBytes` outside the function (as a Class-level variable?)

Comment: Byte arrays dont/cant leak. It is more likley that TIFF file would like to be disposed.  If it has a `Dispose` method, use it.

Comment: Ok, maybe "leak" is the wrong word, but it is definitely the fileBytes() that is not releasing the memory as I have stepped through it and can watch it increment every time it is set, and then it never releases.

Comment: TIFF file does not have a dispose method. And that is not what is holding on to the memory. I am specifically asking how to release the memory from the byte array. Thanks.

Comment: vbnet3d, yes I have tried that (that is how it was originally done) but I get the exact same result.

Comment: vbnet3d, the class is instantiated and then the "SomeMethod" is being called in a loop (basically for each page in the document). I am thinking a complete redesign is probably in order, I just don't have time for that now and was hoping there was a way to get fileBytes to release it's memory when the method is done.

Comment: So to clarify: On this line of code: fileBytes = Array.CreateInstance(GetType(Byte), imageStream.Length) the memory increases roughly 14 MB (very large document with 96 pages). At the end of the function, that 14 MB is never released, so with each call the memory goes up roughly 14-15 MB eventually causing a SystemOutOfMemoryException.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few things, passing the byte array in from the outside and also creating a separate class that does the processing and gets destroyed each round. Neither worked. So I just ended up taking a step back and looking at it. There was no need for the array to get created for every page and then the document get saved after adding the annotation to an individual page. I changed it so that I get the array once before looping through each page and adding the annotations for that page and then just saving once at the end. Simple really, just needed to take a step back and look at it differently rather than assume what was already there was correct.